# Доступ к внешнему элементу

Tags: javascript

Как получить доступ к внешнему атрибуту, в котором находится элемент?

```
<label for="id766793">
     <span class="anune">d<span class="anu">.</span></span> прок
</label>
```

**Так мы получили доступ к элементу :**

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('anune');
```

А как из него, получить доступ к **label**, чтобы узнать значение **for**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var parentElement = elements[0].parentNode.getAttribute("for");
```

Вот так можно получить доступ к родительскому элементу.